# Delete a line with certain text on and the previous two lines?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have quite a few text files that have text in them that I want to remove. The bottom line is consistent but there are two lines about it that are different almost every time. For example:

```
This is the beginning of a junk entry but a different each time
This is junk
-- END OF ENTRY --
```

Is it possible to find the line that says '-- END OF ENTRY --', whether using sed, awk, grep or whatever and remove it and the two previous lines?

I have found a way to replace the text on the bottom line using sed with s/ and /g but I can't search and replace the other two as they change.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Tried sed with search and replace (s/ and /g) but this doesn't help as the two previous lines change all the time.

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: have you tried a web search on something like `delete line and previous 2 lines`?

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), reading the whole file in memory:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
base
This is the beginning of a junk entry but a different each time
This is junk
-- END OF ENTRY --
qux
```

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\n-- END OF ENTRY --//' file
foo
bar
base

qux
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[^\n]+` | any character except: '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `[^\n]+` | any character except: '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `-- END OF ENTRY --` | -- END OF ENTRY -- |